# Mosquitto can't assign requested address inside my Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt, mosquitto, minikube

I'm trying to set up my mosquitto server inside a Kubernetes cluster and somehow I'm getting the following error and I can't figure out why.
Could someone help me?

**Error:**

```
1551171948: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Wed, 13 Feb 2019 00:45:38 +0000) starting
1551171948: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1551171948: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1551171948: |-- ** Configured order: http

1551171948: |-- with_tls=false
1551171948: |-- getuser_uri=/api/mosquitto/users
1551171948: |-- superuser_uri=/api/mosquitto/admins
1551171948: |-- aclcheck_uri=/api/mosquitto/permissions
1551171948: |-- getuser_params=(null)
1551171948: |-- superuser_params=(null)
1551171948: |-- aclcheck_paramsi=(null)
1551171948: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1551171948: Error: Cannot assign requested address
```

**Mosquitto.conf:**

```
allow_duplicate_messages false

connection_messages true

log_dest stdout stderr
log_timestamp true
log_type all

persistence false



listener 1883 mosquitto

allow_anonymous true

# Public

# listener 8883 0.0.0.0

listener 9001 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous false

auth_plugin /usr/lib/mosquitto-auth-plugin/auth-plugin.so
auth_opt_backends http
auth_opt_http_ip 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_http_getuser_uri /api/mosquitto/users
auth_opt_http_superuser_uri /api/mosquitto/admins
auth_opt_http_aclcheck_uri /api/mosquitto/permissions
auth_opt_acl_cacheseconds 1
auth_opt_auth_cacheseconds 0
```

**Kubernetes.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: abb-login
      containers:
        - name: mosquitto
          image: ****mosquitto:develop
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9001
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 1883
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8883
              protocol: TCP

          resources: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "9001"
      port: 9001
      targetPort: 9001
      protocol: TCP
    - name: "1883"
      port: 1883
      targetPort: 1883
      protocol: TCP
    - name: "8883"
      port: 8883
      targetPort: 8883
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
```

Comment: Hi, what is the effect of this error, Is the pod getting killed?

Comment: Yes, it is getting killed

Comment: My guess is this line listener 9001 0.0.0.0

Comment: I think its related to resource , as its empty in your yaml  `resources: {}` you need to provide enough CPU and RAM

Comment: you can use this command to provide the resource
kubectl set resources deployment $DEPLOYMENTNAME --limits=cpu=200m,memory=512Mi --requests=cpu=100m,memory=256Mi

Comment: above values are just for example purpose, you can tune these values according  your needs

Comment: Still the same is not related to resources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189060/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-raven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the listener on port 1883, this can be determined because the log hasn't got to the 9001 listener yet.

The problem is most likely because mosquitto can not resolve the IP address of the hostname `mosquitto`. When passing a hostname the name must resolve to a valid IP address. The same problem has been discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863408/facing-error-while-using-tls-with-mosquitto/54865869#54865869) recent answer. It could also be that `mosquitto` is resolving to an address that is not bound to any of the interfaces on the actual machine (e.g. if Address Translation is being used).

Also for the 9001 listener rather than passing `0.0.0.0` you can just not include a bind address and the default is to listen on all interfaces.