# Facing Error while running mosquitto broker using TLS with mosquitto

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am trying to use TLS for communicating over mqtt. I have ubuntu installed in my system. For using TLS, I have created certificates using the below link:

http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/366/mqtt-over-ssl-tls-with-the-m2mqtt-library-and-the-mosquitto-broker

I am able to create certificates. I have removed `bind_address` from config file. I am starting mosquitto with the new config file with `mosquitto -c mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf -v`. Mosquitto starts, but when I run `mosquitto_sub` command, I am getting error as below:

```
mosquitto -c mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf -v
1551172930: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date 2016-09-21 11:21:45+0530) starting
1551172930: Config loaded from mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf.
1551172930: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1551172930: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
Enter PEM pass phrase:
1551172960: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883.
1551172960: OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
1551172960: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure
1551172960: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

In the window that I am subscribing, I am getting error as below:

```
mosquitto_sub -p 8883 -q 1 -t sensor/temp --cafile /etc/mosquitto/m2mqtt_srv.crt --tls-version tlsv1 -d
Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).
```

Below are the parameters added in config file.

```
port 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/m2mqtt_ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/m2mqtt_srv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/m2mqtt_srv.key
tls_version tlsv1
```

Comment: Did you enter the password asked for?

Comment: I entered the password and then tried running the mosquitto_sub  command.

Comment: Why are you using the `m2mqtt_srv.crt` for the CA cert in the client rather than the `m2mqtt_ca.crt` file?

Comment: Subscriber will be running in server and publisher will run on a device such as a raspberry pi. As I am subscribing at the server itself, I am using m2mqtt_srv.crt.

Comment: Yes, but the `mosquitto_sub` command is explicitly expecting the CA certificate to be passed to the `--cafile` argument. This is also what is in the tutorial you pointed to.

Comment: Yes, but when I tried with m2mqtt_ca.crt in my pc, certificate verification failed. When I tried with m2mqtt_srv.crt, I was able to connect. Also, I was able to publish data on a topic and able to receive as well. Everything worked fine in my pc with windows. But I am facing issues when I am running the same code on a gateway having ubuntu.

Comment: So I need to assign a bind_address in config file as client will be running in Raspberry Pi and publishing to a specific host. When I am running the command with config file with bind_address, I am getting the following error:
`Error: cannot assign requested address`

Comment: Do not use `bind_address` it has NOTHING to do with the SSL errors you are seeing. If you get a failure to verify when using the ca cert then you have messed up generating your certificates.

Comment: The failure to verify when not specifying a host to `mosquitto_sub` is probably because the cert for the broker does not have localhost/127.0.0.1 as a CN or SAN

Answer (score 0):

mosquitto_sub and pub needs a host address or ip. For example i use test.mosquitto.org in my local, download the pem formatted certificate file from this site and added to the conf file just this certificate as "cafile". And here is my command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "test" -p 8883 --cafile "<pem formatted crt file path (downloaded from test.mosquitto.org)>"
```